# how to zoom out in a webview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, webview

I am trying to get a webview with an auto-zoom-level.
I want to show this frame on the complete screen (www.gso.../c00087.htm").
I must zoom out a bit.

When I use the zoomToRect function then the view is not zooming out. The rect is only slyding to the x,y position.

```
[wView.scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 600, 600) animated:NO];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:
           @"http://www.gso-koeln.de/infos/kalender/stupid/06/c/c00087.htm"]];

    [wView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the following property for the UIWebview?

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL scalesPagesToFit;
```

The default is set to NO which means that a page will be set to its natural size and zooming is not possible if the property is not changed to YES. More information available in the class reference:[UIWebview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: When i set scalesPagesToFit (in storyboard) on true i can zoom to zoomToRect but not so how i like to do. It zooms every time from the position 0,0 for the values width,height.

Comment: To access the scrolling characteristics you use the UIWebView property  `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView` and set your UIScrollView behavior here.